# Вывод списка mySQL PHP

Tags: php, sql

Друзья, возник следующий вопрос по выводу данных из таблиц mySQL
цель, вывести данные списком вида:

```
-item    
-item    
-item -item -item    
-item    
-item    
-item -item
```

Каждый item это элемент из списка, ВЕРТИКАЛЬНОГО, не могу сообразить структуру подкатегорий для вывода дополнительных столбцов (если они есть) в подкатегории элемента
то есть, если есть, то вывести подкатегорию элемента, если нет, продолжить одиночный вывод. Запутался, помогите а, в шаблон загружается массив данных из базы пример

```
array([0]=>array([id]=>любой текст));
```

Comment: -item -item -item это разные столбцы одного ряда в таблице?

Comment: это одна таблица из которой выводятся записи

Comment: это понятно, а 

-item

-item -item -item - вот эти две подкатегории откуда? другие колонки в одном ряде?

-item
Структуру таблицы напишите

Comment: Я так понимаю автор собирается хранить многомерный массив в базе.

Comment: Если это будет меню с подкатегориями, то для каждого элемента меню указывать ID родителя и выводить в соответствии с этим.